# How to customize MBProgressHUD view on UIImagePickerController?

Tags: ios, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller, mbprogresshud, activity-indicator

I have inserted a MBProgressHUD view on my image picker controller. It should work as an indicator to take a photo. For this, I customized MBProgressHUD such as below.

```
- (void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
...
CGRect allRect = self.bounds;
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"loadingScreen.png"];
[image drawInRect: allRect];
...
}
```

I have tested this customization code in everywhere, and it always has been success.
But on UIImagePickerController, it doesn't work showing only a indicator and not showing image, "loadingScreen.png".

```
...
HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:imgPicker.view];
[imgPicker.view addSubview: HUD];
...
```

Please help me to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

```
...
HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.view]; // thats not the custom view
HUD.customView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"loadingScreen.png"]];
HUD.mode = MBProgressHUDModeCustomView;
[HUD show:YES];
...
```

Don't forget that "loadingScreen.png" will showed as a still image.